# custom directive's $watch not listening to change in elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to emulate a horizontal scroll-bar. Here is the HTML snippet for the scrollable div

```
<div class="row" scrollable-area>
  <div id="display" class="col-md-6 no-overflow" type="text" onfocus="this.blur()">{{display}}</div>
  <div id="scrollbar" ng-show="isOverflow" class="">
    <div id="scroller" style="width:305px; right:0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

overflow of `div#id` is hidden and its text changes when user presses some buttons, this is controlled by the controller as you can see the interpolation `{{display}}`.

I am trying to display the `div#scrollbar` as the text overflows and reduce the `div#scroller`'s `width` as the overflow grows.

It was working fine when I used a function inside controller returning boolean value to the `div#scrollbar`'s `ng-show` directive. But as `DOM` manipulation is not recommended inside a controller, I am now using a custom directive.

although the `console.log()` inside `scope.$watch` is called when the page loads but it never listens again the change in `scope.currentDisplayScrollWidth`.

```
myapp.directive('scrollableArea',[function() {

  return{link:function (scope, element, attrs) {        

      scope.currentDisplayScrollWidth = element.children()[0].scrollWidth;
      scope.normalDisplayScrollWidth  =element.children()[0].scrollWidth;       

      scope.$watch('currentDisplayScrollWidth', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {

          console.log(scope.currentDisplayScrollWidth+":"+scope.normalDisplayScrollWidth);

          var displayInput= element.children()[0];
          var scroller = angular.element(element.children()[1]).children()[0];

          if(newValue>scope.normalDisplayScrollWidth){

              scope.isOverflow= true;

              displayInput.scrollLeft+=20;

              if( parseFloat(scroller.style.width)>4){
                  scroller.style.width=(parseFloat(scroller.style.width)-1)+"px";
              }
          }
          else{
              isOverflow=false;
              displayInput.scrollLeft=0;
              scroller.style.width="305px";
          }
      },true);
  }
}
}]);
```

Comment: I have faced with this problem too. Have you solved it?